# HSV shading of cone in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I shade the surface of a cone according to the HSV color space?
I'd like to create a drawing similar to this from Wikipedia:

[image]

So far, I have this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
  axis lines=center,
  axis on top,
  domain=0:1,
  y domain=0:2*pi,
  xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
  ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=0.0,
  samples=30]
  \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp] ({x*cos(deg(y))},{x*sin(deg(y))},{x});
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in a cone like this:

[image: cone]

Does anybody know, how to colorize the surface according to the HSV formulars like in the upper image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need here is a "surface plot with explicit color". This plot type allows to assign individual color components for every sample point, and you can choose the color model. Among others, Pgfplots supports the Hsb colors space which is defined as

```
Hsb= hue , saturation , brightness is the same as hsb except that hue is accepted in the interval [0, 360] (degree),
```

The color value as such must be given as argument to `point meta` (which is always the color data in `pgfplots`). The precise syntax is probably best copied from an example, see below.

It seems as if you need polar coordinates of the form `(<angle>, <radius>, <z value>)`. To this end, you can use `data cs=polar` in `pgfplots`.

Taking these items together, I arrive at

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
  axis lines=center,
  axis on top,
  domain=0:1,
  y domain=0:2*pi,
  xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
  ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=0.0,
  samples=30]
  \addplot3 [surf,
    variable=\u,
    variable y=\v,
    data cs=polar,
    mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
    point meta={symbolic={Hsb=deg(v),u,u}},
    shader=interp] 
    ({deg(v)},u,u);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

At first glance, it appears to be close to what you need - at least as starting point. Hopefully, a proper choice of `view/h=<angle>` and some tuning for the parameterization will allow you to derive something like your example.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to Christian's solution as starting point I created this image:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\def\arcbegin{0}
\def\arcending{270}

\begin{axis}[
    view={19}{30},
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top,
    domain=0:1,
    y domain=\arcbegin:\arcending,
    xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
    ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
    zmin=0.0, zmax = 1.2,
    hide axis,
    samples = 20,
    data cs=polar,
    mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
    shader=interp]
% cone:
\addplot3 [
    surf,
    variable=\u,
    variable y=\v,
    point meta={symbolic={Hsb=v,u,u}}] 
    (v,u,u);
% top plane:
\addplot3 [
    surf,
    samples = 50,
    variable=\u,
    variable y=\v,
    point meta={symbolic={Hsb=v,u,1}}] 
    (v,u,1);
% slice plane
\addplot3 [
    surf,
    variable=\u,
    y domain = 0:1,
    variable y=\w,
    point meta={symbolic={Hsb=\arcbegin,u,z}}] 
    (\arcbegin,u,{u+w*(1-u)});
\addplot3 [
    surf,
    variable=\u,
    y domain = 0:1,
    variable y=\w,
        point meta={symbolic={Hsb=\arcending,u,z}}]
    (\arcending,u,{u+w*(1-u)});
% border
\addplot3[
    line width=0.3pt]
    coordinates {(0,0,0) (\arcbegin,1,1) (0,0,1) ({(\arcending)},1,1) (0,0,0) };
% border top
\draw[
    line width = 0.3pt]
    (axis cs: {cos(\arcbegin)}, {sin(\arcbegin)},1) arc (\arcbegin:\arcending:100);
% arc
\draw[
    ->,
    line width = 0.6pt]
    (axis cs: {0.5*cos(\arcbegin+20)}, {0.5*sin(\arcbegin+20)},1) arc ({\arcbegin+20}:{\arcending-20}:50);
% x and z axis
\addplot3[
    ,
    line width=0.6pt]
    coordinates {(\arcbegin,1.1,0) (0,0,0) (0,0,1.45)};
% annotations
\node at (axis cs:1.1,0,0) [anchor=north east] {S};
\node at (axis cs:0,0,1.45) [anchor= north east] {V};
\node at (axis cs:-.5,0.0,1.0) [anchor=east] {H};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: for the record: This code will give a strange result with "newer" PGFPlots versions. Have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330233/correct-use-of-axis-cs) and the corresponding answers to get the desired result (back).