# HSV cone with arrowhead in PGFPLOT

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I would like to replicate the result given in this answer: [Correct use of axis cs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330233/correct-use-of-axis-cs)

[image: HSV cone]

But like in Stefan Pinnow's answers, there is no head arrow for the S and V axis.

I try to change `axis lines=center` by `axis lines=middle` or put others options like several `axis line style={-Latex[round]}` like others forums suggest but it doesn't work.

Also, it's not to be seems a border problem nether.

I try to change the height of vectors but it doesn't work.

Any advices to give head arrow on these axis ?

Answer (score 4):

Stefan's answer includes `hide axis`, which does exactly what it says. The axis lines are instead drawn with an `\addplot3` near the end of the code, after the comment saying `% x and z axis`.

Add `<->` to the options of that `\addplot3` to get this:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % either use a `compat' level below or equal to 1.10, or change
        % `arc' coordinates (as done here)
        compat=1.11,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=stealth,
    ]
            \def\arcbegin{0}
            \def\arcending{270}
        \begin{axis}[
            view={19}{30},
            axis lines=center,
            axis on top,
            domain=0:1,
            y domain=\arcbegin:\arcending,
            xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
            ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
            zmin=0.0, zmax=1.2,
            hide axis,
            samples=20,
            data cs=polar,
            mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
            shader=interp,
        ]
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % also added the "color parts"
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % cone:
            \addplot3 [
                surf,
                variable=\u,
                variable y=\v,
                point meta={symbolic={Hsb=v,u,u}},
            ] (v,u,u);
            % top plane:
            \addplot3 [
                surf,
                samples=50,
                variable=\u,
                variable y=\v,
                point meta={symbolic={Hsb=v,u,1}},
            ] (v,u,1);
            % slice plane
            \addplot3 [
                surf,
                variable=\u,
                y domain=0:1,
                variable y=\w,
                point meta={symbolic={Hsb=\arcbegin,u,z}},
            ] (\arcbegin,u,{u+w*(1-u)});
            \addplot3 [
                surf,
                variable=\u,
                y domain=0:1,
                variable y=\w,
                point meta={symbolic={Hsb=\arcending,u,z}},
            ] (\arcending,u,{u+w*(1-u)});
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % border
            \addplot3 [
                line width=0.3pt,
            ] coordinates {
                (0,0,0) (\arcbegin,1,1) (0,0,1)
                ({(\arcending)},1,1) (0,0,0)
            };
            %%%%%%% border top
            \draw [line width = 0.3pt]
                (axis cs: {cos(\arcbegin)}, {sin(\arcbegin)},1)
%                arc (\arcbegin:\arcending:100)             % <-- old version
                arc (\arcbegin:\arcending:1)                % <-- new version
            ;
            %%%%%%% arc
            \draw [->,line width = 0.6pt]
                (axis cs: {0.5*cos(\arcbegin+20)}, {0.5*sin(\arcbegin+20)},1)
%                arc ({\arcbegin+20}:{\arcending-20}:50)    % <-- old version
                arc ({\arcbegin+20}:{\arcending-20}:0.5)    % <-- new version
            ;
            % x and z axis
            \addplot3[
                <->, %% <------------  added this
                line width=0.6pt,
            ] coordinates {
                (\arcbegin,1.1,0)
                (0,0,0)
                (0,0,1.45)
            };
            % annotations
            \node at (axis cs:1.1,0,0)      [anchor=north east] {S};
            \node at (axis cs:0,0,1.45)     [anchor=north east] {V};
            \node at (axis cs:-.5,0.0,1.0)  [anchor=east]       {H};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot for your explanations