# change point color in tikz polar coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, polarplot

im currently struggling with changing the color of single points in polar coordinates.
I want to create a visualisation for the HSV colorspace by using a cylinder.

Thanks to [HSV shading of cone in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162331/hsv-shading-of-cone-in-pgfplots) ive learnd that you can use `point meta={symbolic={Hsb=v,u,u}}` to get the right color directly from the current coordinates.

But when i change it to a cylinder i get lots of

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
LaTeX
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
LaTeX
```

errors.

My current code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document} 
\begin{axis}[axis equal, data cs=polar]
    
    \addplot3 [surf,
                domain=0:1,
                y domain=0:180,
               samples=20, %number of samples taken
               z buffer=sort,
               shader=interp,
               variable=\u,
               variable y=\v,
               point meta={symbolic={Hsb=u,v,v}}] % the origin of my errors
        (
            {v/2},
            {sin(v/2)},
            {u}
        );
    
    \end{axis}
\end{document}
```

im thinking that it could be that my hacky way of generating the cylinder is causing the problems but i can't wrap my head around it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I see you fixed your MWE to include `mesh/color input = explicit mathparse,`! For posterity, there was also a problem with the HSB "S" for saturation which requires a value in [0,1] to which you were passing `\v` in [0,180].

Just for fun, if you wanted a full cylinder, you can change the domain:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis equal, data cs=polar]
    \addplot3 [
        surf,
        domain = 0:1,
        y domain = 0:360,
        samples = 20, %number of samples taken
        z buffer = sort,
        shader = interp,
        variable = \u, variable y = \v,
        mesh/color input = explicit mathparse,
        point meta={symbolic={Hsb=v,1,u}},
        ] 
        ({v/2},{sin(v/2)},{u});
    \end{axis}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: An open-top cylinder with HSB coloring]
And if you want a half-cylinder with the full color spectrum, just double the Hue:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis equal, data cs=polar]
    \addplot3 [
        surf,
        domain = 0:1,
        y domain = 0:180,
        samples = 20, %number of samples taken
        z buffer = sort,
        shader = interp,
        variable = \u, variable y = \v,
        mesh/color input = explicit mathparse,
        point meta={symbolic={Hsb=2*v,1,u}},
        ] 
        ({v/2},{sin(v/2)},{u});
    \end{axis}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: An open-top half cylinder with HSB coloring]

Comment: Can you please add the resulting pdfs to your answer? Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you! Are png files the way to go, via the image upload feature, or is there a way to upload pdfs? I'm still new to this. Using a latexmk script to generate the png files: [link](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/613-tip-of-the-week-how-to-convert-typeset-pdf-pages-into-raster-image-formats)

Answer (score 2):

I looked again at the code from [HSV shading of cone in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162331/hsv-shading-of-cone-in-pgfplots) and found that i missed to add `mesh/color input=explicit mathparse` to my axis options.

The working code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[axis equal, data cs=polar, mesh/color input=explicit mathparse] % the solution to my problem
    
    \addplot3 [surf,
                domain=0:1,
                y domain=0:180,
               samples=20, %number of samples taken
               z buffer=sort,
               shader=interp,
               variable=\u,
               variable y=\v,
               point meta={symbolic={Hsb=v,1,u}}]
        (
            {v/2},
            {sin(v/2)},
            {u}
        );
    
    \end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiledImage]